# cut off function-Morrey's book

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, metric-spaces

In the book, Multiple Integrals in the Calculus of Variations (1996) Morrey defines a cut off function: (middle of the page 35)

$$\eta=\begin{cases}
1, & \text{on } D\subset D^\prime_a,\\
1-2a^{-1}d(x,D),& \text{ for } 0\le d(x,D)\le a/2,\\
0, & \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}
$$

In page 164 (Lemma 5.7.1) he uses this function and it seems to me that he makes the following estimates:

$$|\nabla \eta|\le C a^{-1},$$

$$|\Delta \eta|\le C a^{-2}.$$

Is that correct or am I misreading?

If yes, can I take third order derivatives of the cut-off function and if the answer is positive to that does it hold that

$$|\nabla^3 \eta|\le C a^{-3}\text{?}$$

Any references for the derivatives of cut off function would be very helpful.

Comment: What properties does $D$ have e.g. closed set? Also what kind of estimates are those? If I'm reading it right, In the case where $D=\{x_0\}$ is a single point then $d(x,D) = |x-x_0|$ which makes $\eta$ only piecewise smooth. Is $\eta$ mollified/smoothed in some way?

Comment: $\bar D$ is compact. However, I am only interested in case D is a ball with center at 0 and radius R. Consider n-dimensional space. About the other questions I am not sure about the answer.

Comment: In this case, $\eta$ is a radial function of $x$, and looks like ‾‾\\_. In particular its not differentiable everywhere. But in the 'transition region', you can compute the gradient (and other derivatives) using the radial coordinates.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.